# how to get the attribute value from each div of dynamically generated content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

I am trying to add product to the cart using jQuery, ajax. But the problem is when ever i use the below listed code, it only returns the product id of first div. My products are dynamically fetched from database. I need the product id of each div on clicking the add to cart bottom.

How can i get the productid of each div on clicking `<p class="btn-icon" value="<%= products[i].id %>" id="value" style="cursor: pointer;">`?

**Jquery Code**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#value').on('click', function(){
                alert($(this).attr('value'))
            })
        })
    </script>
```

**product.ejs**

```
                                <% for( let i = 0; i<products.length; i++) { %>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 product-item">
                                        <div class="pd-bd product-inner">
                                            <div class="product-img">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="../<%= products[i].image[0] %>" alt="" class="img-reponsive"></a>
                                                <div class="ribbon-price red"><span id="discount"><%= products[i].discount %>%</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product-info">
                                                <div class="color-group"></div>
                                                <div class="element-list element-list-left">
                                                    <ul class="desc-list">
                                                        <%- products[i].description %>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="element-list element-list-middle">
                                                    <div class="product-rating bd-rating">
                                                        <span class="star star-5"></span>
                                                        <span class="star star-4"></span>
                                                        <span class="star star-3"></span>
                                                        <span class="star star-2"></span>
                                                        <span class="star star-1"></span>
                                                        <div class="number-rating">( 896 reviews )</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <p class="product-cate"><%= products[i].category[0].category %></p>
                                                    <h3 class="product-title"><a href="#"><%= products[i].title %></a></h3>
                                                    <% if(products[i].discount != 0) { %>
                                                    <% let orginalPrice =  products[i].price %>
                                                    <% let discount =  products[i].discount %>
                                                    <% let newPrice =  orginalPrice - (orginalPrice/100)*discount %>
                                                    <% console.log(newPrice) %>
                                                    <div class="product-bottom">
                                                        <div class="product-price">
                                                            <span class="red" id="new">Rs. <%= newPrice %></span>
                                                            <span class="old" id="old">Rs. <%= products[i].price %></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <a href="#" class="btn-icon btn-view">
                                                            <span class="icon-bg icon-view"></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <% } else { %>
                                                    <div class="product-bottom">
                                                        <div class="product-price"><span>Rs. <%= products[i].price %> </span></div>
                                                        <a href="#" class="btn-icon btn-view">
                                                            <span class="icon-bg icon-view"></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div> 
                                                    <% } %>
                                                    <!-- <div class="product-bottom-group">
                                                        <button class="btn-icon" id="add-to-cart">
                                                            <span class="icon-bg icon-cart" id="add-to-cart"></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                        <a href="#" class="btn-icon">
                                                            <span class="icon-bg icon-wishlist"></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <a href="#" class="btn-icon">
                                                            <span class="icon-bg icon-compare"></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div> -->
                                                    <div class="product-button-group">
                                                        <p class="btn-icon" value="<%= products[i].id %>" id="value" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                                            <span class="icon-bg icon-cart"></span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p href="#" class="btn-icon" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                                            <span class="icon-bg icon-wishlist"></span>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p href="#" class="btn-icon" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                                            <span class="icon-bg icon-compare"></span>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>          
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <% } %>
```

Comment: Instead of fetching by id why not fetch by class? You would need to add a class value to each item.

Comment: will that give the result?

Comment: What div's contains the productid?

Comment: ```<p class="btn-icon" value="<%= products[i].id %>" id="value" style="cursor: pointer;">``` this particular line contain the product id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for an ID. Just use the right selector to identify the first `<p>` tag within each of the `.product-button-group` divs:

```
$('.product-button-group > p:first-child').on('click', function(){
  alert($(this).attr('value'))
})
```

Comment: Thanks Man this worked. Just wanted to know how to select the second and third child?

Comment: @xetryDcoder You can use `.product-button-group > p:nth-child(2)` to select the 2nd child. Change 2 to 3 for the 3rd child.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the dynamic ID, use the class name.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn-icon[value]').on('click', function(){
            alert($(this).attr('value'))
        })
    })
</script>
```

The `.btn-icon[value]` selector returns all elements with the class `btn-icon` that have a `value` attribute.